# example of MPI thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi

I have install MPI and found simple example of thread that I'm don't fully understand. Can I get a simple example of MPI thread that prints something. Thanks

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int errs = 0;
int provided, flag, claimed;

MPI_Init_thread(0, 0, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided); //what does it MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE mean

MPI_Is_thread_main(&flag); //why there is flag here
if (!flag) {
    errs++;  //why there is counter for errs
    printf("..."); fflush(stdout); // doesn't print anything
}
MPI_Finalize();
//return errs;  I get error here
```

Comment: What part exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Added few comments to the code

Comment: https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Init_thread.3.php